# How is List a monad?

Tags: scala, monads

I think I have a basic grasp of Monads and monadic operations but am still a bit stuck on understanding how the magic features of a monadic type get added to the underlying type (hope this makes sense).

For example, I [was reading](http://debasishg.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/monads-another-way-to-abstract.html) about how a `List[T]` is a monad. But if I `flatMap` and `map` over some Lists sequentially in a `for` comprehension then isn't it really `flatMap` and `map` that are providing the monadic magic?

If I create a `List<String>` then how is the monadic magic added? Or is a `List<T>` always a monad in Scala because it just happens to be one of those containers that the language already provides in-built monadic support for?

Comment: List as a data structure is not a Monad, but the fact that Scala's List implements flatMap is what gives it its monadic super-powers. It also needs to fulfil [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), left unit and right unit laws to qualify as a Monad.

Comment: There's no magic. Only laws.

Comment: I think you'll love this link https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/demystifying-the-monad-in-scala-cc716bb6f534#.9zklh4ug4

Comment: @hasumedia, thanks for the comment and the link.

Comment: Hope this helps: [Why do they say "List is a Monad"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-do-say-list-monad-yuan-hefeng)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're exactly right that `flatMap` and `map` are providing the "monadic magic." There is fortunately or unfortunately (depending on how much bad code you've seen) no magic in programming. No amount of abstraction will save you (or someone else) from ultimately writing the code that does the thing you want. Abstraction "just" lets you re-use previously written code and clarify your thoughts around a problem. A monad then is just a concept, an idea, an abstraction, etc.

In the case of Scala this is very literally what the compiler does to a `for` comprehension, which becomes a series of `flatMap`, `map`, `withFilter`, and `filter` statements.

A monad (in Scala) can be thought of as just a label for the phenomenon where you happen to have a type constructor `T[_]` and two functions<sup>1</sup>

```
def f0[A](x: T[A], f: X => T[A]): T[A]
def f1[A](x: A): T[A]
```

By convention, when they see this phenomenon, the Scala community calls `f0` `flatMap` and usually make it a method so that the `x` is always the parent class instead of a separate argument. There is also a convention to call `f1` `point` or `pure` (see `scalaz` or `cats`). `f1` is also usually a method so that it doesn't end up explicitly taking an argument and just uses its parent class as the `x`.

Whenever anyone says "such-and-such" is a monad, there is always an implied `f0` and `f1` which the speaker expects the listener to infer. Strictly speaking "`List` is a monad" is a mild abuse of terminology. It's short-hand for `List` along with the functions `(xs: List[A], f: A => List[A]) => xs.map(f).flatten` (which forms `f0`) and `(x: A) => List(x)` (which forms `f1`) form a monad. Or slightly less obtusely, `List` along with the standard `flatMap` on lists and the `List.apply` constructor form a monad.

**Therefore there was never any magic. As part of classifying something as a `Monad` you had to have provided a notion of `flatMap` and `pure`**.

There are many ways you could turn this abstraction of a monad into code. The naive way (i.e. Scala with no third-party libraries) is to just agree on a common name for `f0` and `f1` (e.g. `flatMap`) and just name your methods that have the appropriate type signature those names. That is essentially what `scalac` expects you to do for `for` comprehensions. You could go one step further and try to formalize things with a `trait` or an `abstract class`. Maybe call it `Monad` to be cute and have something like the following:

```
trait Monad[A] {
  def flatMap(f: A => Monad[A]): Monad[A]

  def pure(x: A): Monad[A]
}
```

Then you might call anything that extends this `Monad` an implementation of the monad idea (you might imagine something such as `class List[A] extends Monad[A]`).

For a variety of practical reasons this turns out to be less than satisfactory and so you end up with the usual solution that looks something like (hand-waving away a lot of other complexity)

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def flatMap[A](f: A => F[A]): F[A]

  def pure[A](x: A): F[A]
}
```

that gets implemented by `implicit`s.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. And some laws/conventions governing their interaction. The practical reason for the existence of those laws is to lend sanity to programmer's lives so they know what to expect when someone tells them that these functions are "monadic." These laws are exactly what makes reasoning about constructs such as monads so useful, but I won't delve into them here because they're adequately explained elsewhere.

Comment: so we can call "List in Scala" is monad, right? Because List in Scala implements 2 methods that form a monad definition. thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`Monad` is a *concept* not a class or trait.
So as `List[T]` fulfills all requirements of a monad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming) it can be called `monadic`.
So plainly spoken it is a monad because it has all functions and abilities a monad provides so it is a monad.

If you want some more guarantess and express *being a monad* more explicitely you can for example use `Scalaz`.
This link shows how and provides also a detailed look at the monad laws: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+laws.html

Answer (score -1):

From a pure perspective, `List` may not be a monad. At least that is how I perceive it based on the left identity rule:

```
unit(x).flatMap(f) == f(x)
```

If the left identity rule is upheld by `List` then the following should be true:

```
List(2).flatMap(e => e*e) == 4
```

But it is not, the compiler will barf while you code if you try the code above.

Comment: This is plain wrote.  Your example fails because `e => e*e` does not have the proper type `flatMap`'s function argument.  That is, you are passing an `Int => Int` where you should be passing an `Int => List(Int)`.  You can fix this by passing `e => List(e*e)`.  Then we have `List(2).flatMap(e => List(e*e)) == List(4)`.  Both the identity and the associativity laws hold for `List`'!